# Parse facebook login not working anymore

Tags: android, facebook, sdk, parse-platform, facebook-login

So I basically worked on this yesterday and had it running and now it doesn't work anymore. Already spent three hours with other people to get it working but we have no idea what is happening. The last message in logcat says the session doesnt have a id or client token but this is literaly the same code from yesterday similar to the parse tutorial: search "parse intergrating facebook in android" (cant post 2 links)

[Here is the logcat](http://pastebin.com/KFPYSzuc) (cant get 4 spaces on it)

I am aware that it says "Warning: Sessionless Request needs token but missing either application ID or client token." but I have provided these as explained in the tutorial.

Comment: Okay so appareantly the parse tutorial never mentions that you have to put your facebook app id and secret in your parse application settings on the website. Which is weird because you configure the app_id string in your facebook app but hey it works!